# What is the meaning of "How choice"

Tags: meaning

So, this is from the musical Sweeney Todd, where Todd sings to Mrs. Lovett in *A Little Priest*:

*Mrs. Lovett, how I lived without you all these years I'll never know. How delectable, also undetectable. **How choice,** how rare.*

I don't quite grasp the meaning behind it.

Comment: Choice means "high quality", as in "choice cuts of meat". Synonyms are "prime", "excellent", "superior", "first-class".

Comment: Okay, so, _choice_ is an adjective there. And it is part of the _how + adjective_ phrase. It is basically denoting the level of 'choiceness'. Thanks! @SethJeffery

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple unfamiliarity with an adjectival form. The question would probably have fitted better on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), but since OP has his answer, there is no need to migrate it.

Comment: Note that "choice", in this sense, tends to be use sarcastically with considerable frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a premium choice or example essentially becomes a metric as 
to how "choice" that selection is. It feels like slang, but is a legitimate use, often used in describing foodstuffs like the earlier comment pointed out. There is another adjectival usage, but that usage puts a harsh or rude spin on the word, with respect to speech, a la "having some choice words with someone".  Even then it could be viewed as selecting the premium words for that kind of verbal abuse.

Comment: Right, I get it now. I wasn't aware of the adjectival function of _choice_. It is crystal clear now. Thank you!

Comment: Could you accept this answer?  Or maybe Seth Jeffery can submit his comment as an answer and you could accept that one, since he was technically first (and correct).

Comment: I tried to do that yesterday, but it seems I'm not very familiar with the website yet.